# Name of these determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology

How are these determinants called? In my course the term used are 'diagonal determinants' but I didn't find this term on internet

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)

Comment: yeah, I know about minors but isn't a special term for these minors?Minor is any small square matrix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are called *leading principal minors*.

"Minors" are determinants of square submatrices.

The word "principal" means that the indices of the rows retained are precisely the indices of the columns retained.

If, in addition, the index set is $\{1,2,\ldots,k\}$ for some $k$, those minors are called "leading principal minors". If the matrix is $n\times n$, there are exactly $n$ leading principal minors.

Of the $3\times3$ example matrix in your question,
$$
\left|\matrix{5&1\\ 3&0}\right|
$$
is a minor but not a principal minor, while
$$
\left|\matrix{4&1\\ 1&2}\right| \text{ or } \left|\matrix{3&0\\ 8&2}\right|
$$
are principal minors but not *leading* principal minors.

The terms "principal submatrices" and "leading principal submatrices" are defined analogously, if you don't take determinants but look at the submatrices themselves.